# Passing a controller to a directive in angularJS. Gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working to add modals to my directives using ui-bootstrap and did so fine on the previous directive. I don't believe I am doing anything differently in this one but I get the **ReferenceError: milestoneController is not defined** when I run the **edit()** function from within the directive.

milestone.html *(this is the template HTML for the directive below)*:

```
<div ng-controller = "milestoneController"></div>
```

milestone directive:

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('milestone', function (milestoneFactory,$modal) {
     return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {             
            objectid:'@objectid'
        },
        templateUrl: '/ireg/components/milestone/milestone.html',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.edit = function(data) {
                milestoneController.editMilestoneDialog(data);
            };

        }

    }
});

angular.module('ireg').controller('milestoneController', function ($scope, $modal){
   $scope.editMilestonesDialog = function (objectid) {
        //fun
   }
});
```

EDIT: I allso felt I should mention that the milestone directive is repeated in a ng-repeat loop. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the connection between directive and `ng-controller`? Can you show that in markup? You can't arbitrarily use a controller object inside your directive

Comment: @charlietfl yep, the HTML that 'ng-controller' is in is the template for the directive.

Comment: Is that controller for the whole modal? Giving us snippets doesn't help without seeing better scope structure in html

Comment: Sorry, I understand the confusion now. There is a main controller being used when the milestone directive is created. The controller cited is simply for my milestone module. I've been trying to encapsulate all the above into simply the milestone directive

Comment: My suspicion is all that code could probably reside in directive without controller.

Comment: @charlietfl yep. That simple, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

ok you're going to want to use a transcluded scope in your directive to pass a controller function to the directive. Your directive now becomes:

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('milestone', function (milestoneFactory,$modal) {
     return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {             
            objectid:'@objectid',
            editMilestoneDialog:'&'
        },
        templateUrl: '/ireg/components/milestone/milestone.html',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        $scope.edit = function(data) {
            $scope.editMilestoneDialog(data);
        };

    }

}
```

and your markup becomes:

```
<milestone edit-milestone-dialog="editMilestoneDialog"></milestone>
```

Comment: This does stop the error. Unfortunately editMilestoneDialog isn't the scope when milestone is placed in the html becuase it is the controller for the directive so I believe it is passing an empty function. 
Am I not using controllers and directives where I should?

Comment: You might be, can you add a plunker with what you're trying to do so i can take a closer look.